# HOWTO do relative seek on a mysql resultset with PHP ? / HOWTO get currentrownumber of mysql resultset?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do relative seek on a mysql resultset, more specifically +1/-1 seeks.

The function `mysql_data_seek()` provides absolute seek and there does not seem to any method to get current row number!! (Should I implement my own counter, it would require updating a large code base)

For +1, mysql_fetch_array() would do the trick but still I need a solution for -1.

Comment: Why can't you keep track of the row number? Then just increment / decrement it?

Comment: the mysql_fetch_array might be called from several locations in the source code. If I want to keep track of row number safely I would need to encapsulate resulset and mysql_fetch_array. As well I would have to update all code base to use this new encapsulation.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to rethink your code design.  There is no command to get the current row number.

Comment: @GWW You are right. I had no choice but to change the design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no solution.

Seems to be a design flaw in php mysql api. It provides the expensive operation (seeking) but not the cheap one ( getting current row number).

EDIT: I checked with PHP team, mysql api is frozen and only accept bug fix. I should switch to mysqli.